# OMAC/CMAC constant for different block sizes

Tags: cbc-mac

OMAC/CMAC only specifies constants for 64-bit `(0x1B)` and 128-bit `(0x87)` block size. I would like to know how to get constants for other block sizes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMAC says it *"is the non-leading coefficients of the lexicographically first irreducible degree-b binary polynomial with the minimal number of ones."*, but I'm not good at math and I don't know how to implement that.

So does anybody know how to implement that?

Thanks.

Comment: the [crypto++ implementation of CMAC](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/cmac_8cpp_source.html) specifies the constants for 64, 128, and 256-bit block sizes, if that's any help.

Comment: I really wanted to know how to get it for any block size. Anyway, it semms incorrect to me. It should be `0x425` not `0x423`.

Comment: I believe the polynomial for a 512-bit block cipher, like Kalyna, is x^512 + x^8 + x^5 + x^2 + 1. I know that's Kalyna's polynomial for GCM mode because the Kalyna team provided it in [DSTU 7624:2014](http://ukrndnc.org.ua/). I'm not sure if it applies to other modes, like CMAC, or other block ciphers, like Threefish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The identification of the *lexicographically first irreducible degree-b binary polynomial with the minimal number of ones* can be implemented by testing reducibility ([second algorithm](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/ANZMC08t4.pdf#page=3)) of those

polynomials in order until you get to the first irreducible polynomial in that order.

Alternatively, you could [look them up](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-135.pdf).

The constant itself is then derived from the polynomial by discarding the leading (block size) term and evaluating the remainder for $x = 2$.

e.g. for 256-bit block size:

- first polynomial is $x^{256} + x^{10} + x^5 + x^2 + 1$ 

  Note this is is `256,10,5,2` in the linked report, which discards the $+1$ term.
- discarding first term and evaluating for $x = 2$ gives $2^{10} + 2^5 + 2^2 + 1 = 0x425$

Comment: Why not first algorithm?

Comment: I misinterpreted that paper and thought it was saying that the second algorithm was $\hspace{1.18 in}$ faster than the first algorithm. $\:$ The first algorithm is fine. $\;\;\;$